# C passing array to pthread in Dining Philosopher

Tags: c, arrays, pthreads

I'm writing code for the Dining Philosopher thread problem for N number of philosophers from user input. I get an error for dereferencing `void *` pointer. What am I doing wrong specifically with passing in the array?

```
 void *philosopher(void *arg_l);

 int main()
 {   
     int i,A,B;
     scanf("%10d", &A);
     scanf("%10d", &B);
     printf("You got %d phils and %d turns each\n",A,B);

     int args[2];
     args[0] = A;
     args[1] = B;

     pthread_t thread_id[A];
     sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
     for(i=0;i<A;i++)
         sem_init(&S[i],0,0);
     for(i=0;i<A;i++)
     {
         args[2] = phil_num[i];
         pthread_create(&thread_id[i],NULL,philosopher,&args);
         printf("Philosopher %d is thinking\n",i+1);
     }
     for(i=0;i<A;i++)
         pthread_join(thread_id[i],NULL);
}

void *philosopher(void *arg_l)
{
    arg_l[0] = int A;
    arg_l[1] = int B;
    ...
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You need to cast `arg_l` back to the original type before you can dereference it. Otherwise, how does it know what type `arg_l[0]` is?

Comment: `int A` is not valid syntax in an assignment.

Comment: How would you recommend this be done?

Comment: as in the answer that @dbush posted

Comment: Note: `args[2] = phil_num[i];` is writing out of bounds.  You have to pass each philosopher a separate array because there is no guarantee that a given thread will have read the information before the main thread reassigns a new value.  Usually, you'll use a structure, not an array, for the data passed to an individual thread; you have an initialized array of those structures so that each thread gets its own unique control information.  I don't think this is covered by Mr Bush's answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Is there any way you can give an example of this, or provide reference to somewhere so i could see what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lines like:

```
arg_l[0] = int A;
```

are completely broken.  You would get away with:

```
int A = ((int *)arg_l)[0];
```

You cannot dereference a `void *` validly, nor can you index them (in part because that requires dereferencing, in part because in standard C — as opposed to GNU C — the `sizeof(void)` is undefined).  You need to convert to an appropriate type with a cast and then derefence, as shown.

Note: `args[2] = phil_num[i];` is writing out of bounds (you define `int args[2];` but it appears you need `int args[3];`.

You have to pass each philosopher a separate array because there is no guarantee that a given thread will have read the information before the main thread reassigns a new value. Usually, you'll use a structure, not an array, for the data passed to an individual thread; you have an initialized array of those structures so that each thread gets its own unique control information.

> Is there any way you can give an example of this?

Somewhat like this.  The key point is the array of `struct Info`, each of which is separately initialized (using a C99 compound literal) and a different element of the array is passed to each thread so that it gets its own data, rather than trying to share data with other threads.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

struct Info
{
    int number;
    int turns;
    int diner;
};

enum { MAX_PHILOSOPHERS = 10 };
enum { MAX_TURNS = 99 };
static sem_t mutex;
static sem_t S[MAX_PHILOSOPHERS];
static void *philosopher(void *arg_l);

int main(void)
{
    int A, B;
    printf("How many philosophers? How many turns? ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%d %d", &A, &B) != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (A < 2)
        fprintf(stderr, "You specified too few philosophers (%d)\n", A);
    if (A > MAX_PHILOSOPHERS)
        fprintf(stderr, "You specified too many philosophers (%d, but the maximum is %d)\n",
                A, MAX_PHILOSOPHERS);
    if (B < 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "You specified too few turns (%d)\n", B);
    if (B > MAX_TURNS)
        fprintf(stderr, "You specified too many turns (%d, but the maximum is %d)\n",
                B, MAX_TURNS);
    if (A < 2 || A > MAX_PHILOSOPHERS || B < 1 || B > MAX_TURNS)
        return 1;
    printf("You have %d philosophers who get %d turns each\n", A, B);

    /* This assignment could be in the thread creation loop before pthread_create() */
    /* Or in the loop that uses sem_init() */
    struct Info info[A];
    for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
        info[i] = (struct Info){ A, B, i};

    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
        sem_init(&S[i], 0, 0);

    pthread_t thread_id[A];
    for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, philosopher, &info[i]);
        printf("Philosopher %d is thinking\n", i + 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);

    printf("Dinner is over\n");
    return 0;
}

static void *philosopher(void *arg_l)
{
    struct Info *info = arg_l;
    printf("N = %d, T = %d, I = %d\n", info->number, info->turns, info->diner);
    /* ...do dining stuff; remember to share nicely!... */
    return 0;
}
```

The `#pragma` allows the code to compile on macOS Sierra, which doesn't have working versions of the `<semaphore.h>` functions — they just return an error indication and set `errno` to `ENOSYS` (function not implemented).
This code should check the return value of the pthread functions and the semaphore operations too — it is being lazy not to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Since `arg_l` has type `void *`, you can't use the subscript operator `[]` on it.  That would mean each element has type `void`, which cannot be instantiated.  Also, the syntax on the right side of the assignment is not valid.

You need to cast the thread argument to `int *` before you can use it.  Also, you need to pass in `args` without taking its address, since an array decays into a pointer to the first element when passed to a function.

```
pthread_create(&thread_id[i],NULL,philospher,args);

...

void *philospher(void *arg_l)
{
     int *args = arg_l;
     ...

}
```